# My made programs are detected as a virus on other computers

Tags: visual-studio, c++-cli, virus

So, I've made a simple game in visual studio using c++/cli. I tried to open it on other computers, but on some, they don't even open/detects it as a virus and on others it does open but still detects as a virus.

I'm pretty new on using visual studio, so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Submit your binary to the vendor of the security solution and notify of a false positive.

In one of my previous companies we did just that when we had a popular antivirus solution detecting one of our JS libraries as malware. In a day or two the false positive went away.

Comment: Thanks ! But there's still another problem , the program on some computers doesn't even open. How is this fixable ?

Comment: If the AV blocks it it's quite normal it doesn't open. If you bypass the AV and it still doesn't open, then you should probably install the [VC++ runtime library](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2977003)